# Social icons(facebook) changing the image colours from black to white on Darkmode(android phone)?

Tags: html, email, mailer, darkmode

I placing the social icons on my mailer template.

There is some issues in specifically facebook icon, on DARKMODE(android phone) of gmail its converting into white colour. I used the png transparent with grey colour.

Any suggestion or solution, it's useful.

Thanks in advance.